# Efficiently add multiple items to arraylist object to avoid out of bounds exception when sending intent to another activity in android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to find a way to efficiently add multiple add statements to an array list of an object.

For example:

In my MainActivity (cut down version) I'm adding to the array of a car object there's quite a few:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ArrayList<Car> imagesArray = new ArrayList<>();


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    imagesArray.add(new Car(0,"alpha", "", R.mipmap.alpha));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(1,"audi", "", R.mipmap.audi));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(2,"bentley", "", R.mipmap.bentley));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(3,"bmw", "", R.mipmap.bmw));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(4,"bugatti", "", R.mipmap.bugatti));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(5,"ferrari", "", R.mipmap.ferrari));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(6,"ford", "", R.mipmap.ford));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(7,"honda", "", R.mipmap.honda));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(8,"hyundai", "", R.mipmap.hyundai));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(9,"jaguar", "", R.mipmap.jaguar));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(10,"jeep", "", R.mipmap.jeep));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(11,"lamborghini", "", R.mipmap.lamborghini));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(12,"maserati", "", R.mipmap.maserati));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(13,"mazda", "", R.mipmap.mazda));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(14,"mercedes", "", R.mipmap.mercedes));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(15,"mini", "", R.mipmap.mini));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(16,"mustang", "", R.mipmap.mustang));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(17,"nissan", "", R.mipmap.nissan));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(18,"pagani", "", R.mipmap.pagani));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(19,"porsche", "", R.mipmap.porsche));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(20,"rangerover", "", R.mipmap.rangerover));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(21,"renault", "", R.mipmap.renault));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(22,"rollsroyce", "", R.mipmap.rollsroyce));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(23,"seat", "", R.mipmap.seat));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(24,"skoda", "", R.mipmap.skoda));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(25,"subaru", "", R.mipmap.subaru));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(26,"suzuki", "", R.mipmap.suzuki));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(27,"tesla", "", R.mipmap.tesla));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(29,"toyota", "", R.mipmap.toyota));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(30,"volvo", "", R.mipmap.volvo));
    imagesArray.add(new Car(31,"vw", "", R.mipmap.vw));

    Button btnHints = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hints);


    btnHints.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.i("Home Screen","Hints Clicked.");
            openHintsActivity();

        }
    });

 }

   public void openHintsActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Hints.class);
    intent.putExtra("imagesArray", imagesArray);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
```

Here's the car object:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

int id;
String make;
String model;
int mipmap;

public Car(int id,String make, String model, int mipmap) {
    this.id = id;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.mipmap = mipmap;
}

//Getters and setters etc. below
```

The issue is SOMETIMES I get an out of bounds exception whenever I pass the intent over to another activity, I'm guessing this might be to do with the size of the array?

I have a feeling that sometimes this happens because when the application gets started not all the images are added before a user goes onto another activity so the entire intent of imagesArray isn't, complete?

As imagesArray is used in other functions in the application.

So my question is how is it best to efficiently to get around this out of bounds issue when adding a large amounts of data to an array list to then be passed as an intent? Is there a better solution?

Thanks for your advice.

Array is used here:

```
public class Hints extends AppCompatActivity {

StringBuilder temp;
int noOfAttempts = 0;
ArrayList<Car> imagesArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hints);

    imagesArray = (ArrayList<Car>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("imagesArray");

    Collections.shuffle(imagesArray); //Randomizes array

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);

    final int randomMake = imagesArray.get(0).getId();
    imageView.setImageResource(imagesArray.get(randomMake).getMipmap());
```

Comment: Can you share the full code of MainActivity ?? Most importantly neven do heavy stuff in Oncreate() Method. You can move the adding statement  in another method and call these method from OnResume().

Comment: I've added more to main activity now so you can see how it gets passed to hints activity. Will OnResume() run like OnCreate? So will activate as soon as the application starts? Apologies fairly new to the android platform but learning as I go!

Comment: onCreate() : When a user first opens an activity than the first method that gets called is called as 
onCreateonResume(): It is called just before the user starts interacting with the application.

Could you please add the code where you create your intent ?? Where is the code of openHintsActivity() method? please provide these method

Comment: Thanks. It should be at the bottom of Mainactivity.

Comment: Is it working Now ??

Comment: I've popped all the adds in an onResume() method, but when I switch between MainActivity and Hints quickly and repeatedly a few times the out of bounds exception comes up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Hints Activity Change

```
    imagesArray = (ArrayList<Car>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("imagesArray");

    Collections.shuffle(imagesArray); //Randomizes array

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);

    final int randomMake = imagesArray.get(0).getId();
    imageView.setImageResource(imagesArray.get(randomMake).getMipmap());
```

To

```
imagesArray = (ArrayList<Car>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("imagesArray");
Random random = new Randome();
final int randomMake = random.nextInt(imagesArray.size());
imageView.setImageResource(imagesArray.get(randomMake).getMipmap());
```

To Make Sure You Are Not Getting A Number Higher Than The Array

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now, but when using Random() what if for example I had randomMake2 and randomMake3? The reason I used collections.shuffle was so that I can get more than 1 unique random make from the given list which would avoid getting duplicates of the shuffled array by doing .get(0), .get(1) etc.

Comment: I Understood But Notice You Will Got Duplicates With `collections.shuffle();` , There Is Several Ways You Can Do That, The Easiest `Removing the element After Using It` 
OR Generate An integer ListArray `List<Integer> randomPositions` And Lopp Through it To Add Numbers From imagesArray.size() To Zero Then Shuffle This List And Use iT As Indexes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you might be able to use an if statement to check if the randomMake variable is greater than the array length, and then just use the array length as the index. You could also use a try catch block for the indexOutOfBounds exception, and then just use the array length as the index.

*I know it's called an arrayList, but array sounds better when I read it.